# IDN U-Label to A-Label wrong with many services

Tags: internet, unicode, url, international

I own the Unicode Domain `κλαρα-σωλις.ευ`, which should be converted to `xn----ylba7abgd9bnh0e.xn--qxa6a`, but many services convert the URL to `xn----ylba7abgd9buc7d.xn--qxa6a`.

Websites like `https://www.punycoder.com/` and `https://dencode.com/string` return the wrong A-Label version.

This is causing issues with GMail and Outlook, because they can't resolve my domain, and I can't send E-Mails to my Mail-Server.

Does anybody know the root cause of this wrong Conversion? Is there maybe a Library which does this wrong? Or do they use an Obsolete Standard?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your domain was registered using the IDNA2008 rules, but those services use the old IDNA2003 rules (or IDNA2008 with "[TR46](https://unicode.org/reports/tr46/#IDNAComparison) Transitional Processing", which is compatible with IDNA2003). The first tool actually mentions this in its front page.

The character [U+03C2](https://util.unicode.org/UnicodeJsps/character.jsp?a=03C2) `ς` is one of the [four](https://unicode.org/reports/tr46/#TableDerivationStep4) characters that have [different encodings](https://util.unicode.org/UnicodeJsps/list-unicodeset.jsp?a=%5Cp%7Bage%3D3.2%7D-%5Cp%7Bcn%7D-%5Cp%7Bcs%7D-%5Cp%7Bco%7D&abb=on&g=uts46+idna+idna2008) in the two standards (while still being valid in both). In the old rules, it is [*mapped*](https://util.unicode.org/UnicodeJsps/list-unicodeset.jsp?a=%5B:Idn_Mapping=%CF%83:%5D) to U+03C3 `σ`, while in the new rules it is a valid character on its own.